# Conditional rendering of the forms make them share same state

Tags: reactjs, forms, conditional-statements, share, state

I was trying to render some forms conditionally based on EDIT/VIEW mode and noticed that they are sharing same state! Asking just to understand what's going on and is there a way out of such cases. I know one approach would be; inside Form component to make both edit and view mode and pass the flag for editMode as prop, but was interested particularly in this case. Have tried the same using `ref` for each form and same thing happens. I've included a `jsfiddle` for the case I'm talking about!

Guide: Inputs in the top show the case when they are both shown and no conditional rendering is involved. Input in the bottom has a button to change between VIEW/EDIT mode and renders the appropriate input based on the mode. Typing on them on each mode make them share the state(or maybe same input is being rendered for both cases)

[Conditional form rendering JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s3dqbnLa/2/)

Comment: Your conditionally creating the same element, create 2 seperate ones.  Use composition to save repeating code.  Maybe name NameFormEdit and NameFormView, etc

Comment: It's strange because props are being passed properly! Coming from angular this is like the case when directive has no isolated scope!

Comment: React is based on a virtual DOM, this virtual DOM is compared to create the real DOM.   In your example in both cases the virtual DOM are going to be the same, only difference is the Props, but its totally valid that a re-render changes the Props, but doesn't re-generate a new DOM node.  If you want the state isolated, you either create 2 instances and just change visibility, or create 2 different Element types, this will let the virtual DOM comparison know they are different Elements.  But the best solution is not to store state in the component in the first place, eg. use Redux etc.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Actually was thinking for the key prop and seems the guy below already answered it and kind of it does the job. Regarding instances, that's what i was looking for. How to make distinct instances! Tried with HOC, no success. As for redux i believe it adds too much complicity for very simple actions (using mobx for other cases). This is form's internal state so it's ok to use state here i think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-render the input,you can add key property for NameForm,then after click  "Toggle mode" , React will re-render the NameForm component.

```
  <div className="row">
  {
    isEditMode
    ? <div className="col">
    <NameForm name="View mode from" key="1"/>
  </div>
  :  <div className="col">
    <NameForm name="Edit mode from" key="2"/>
  </div>
  }
  </div>
```

Comment: Thought about it and you already answered. Will wait if there are other approaches before marking it as answer!